# Hidden iFrame file upload submits an extra time on each subsequent submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, iframe

I'm trying to create a simple file upload form for my website.  I'm using a hidden iFrame to do it "ajax" style so I can have a user upload files one after another using the same form.

Right now I have a form with an `<input type="file" />`. What I have happening is when the input field changes(user selects a file) it should submit the form with the target set to the iFrame which loads a php script and then reset the input field to allow the user to upload again.  What seems to happen is the form gets submitted based on the amount of times the form was submitted. e.g if you press the button when the page loads it will submit one time, however if you press the button again(without reloading the page) it will submit two times, and when you press the button for a third time it will submit the form three times and so on.

Here is my javascript for when the input changes

newupload is the id of the input
newimgform is the id of the form
postframe is the id of the iframe

```
$("#newupload").change(function() {
    var max = 5242880, iframe = $("#postframe"), iframeContents;
    $('#newimgform').attr("action", "uploadPicture.php")
    $('#newimgform').attr("method", "post")
    $('#newimgform').attr("MAX_FILE_SIZE", max)
    $('#newimgform').attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data")
    $('#newimgform').attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data")
    $('#newimgform').attr("target", "postframe")
    $('#newimgform').submit();
    $("#postframe").load(function() {
        iframeContents = jQuery.parseJSON($(this.contentDocument).find('body').html());
        alert(iframeContents.filename);
    $("#newimgform")[0].reset();
    });
});
```

I looked for anyone else trying this and I've seen some answers on here that talk about the submit is being bound multiple times and I need to use unbind like `$('#newimgform').unbind("submit").submit();` but that doesn't seem to do anything.  I can't use any flash uploaders or anything so this has to be pure html/javascript/php.

Comment: Is the change handler getting added multiple times?

Comment: The problem was the iframe load handler being called inside the change function. Fixed thanks to ShankarSangoli and Jasper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move out the iframe load handler because it need not be added every time you upload a file. And also you can optimize your code like this.

```
$("#newupload").change(function() {
    $('#newimgform').attr({
       action: "uploadPicture.php",
       method: "post",
       MAX_FILE_SIZE: 5242880,
       enctype: "multipart/form-data",
       encoding: "multipart/form-data",
       target: "postframe",
    }).submit();
});

$("#postframe").load(function() {
    var iframeContents = jQuery.parseJSON($(this.contentDocument).find('body').html());
    alert(iframeContents.filename);
    $("#newimgform")[0].reset();
});
```

Comment: +1, for some reason I hadn't thought to pass an object to `.attr()`. Also not using the `var` statement in the `load` event handler is creating a global variable.

Comment: This did it perfectly!  I guess the form wasn't submitting multiple times just the iframe kept doing the load function multiple times!  Thank you it was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `load` event handler outside the `change` event handler. As it is, everytime you change the value of `#newupload`, a new event handler is bound to the `#postframe` element:

```
$("#postframe").load(function() {
    var iframeContents = jQuery.parseJSON($(this.contentDocument).find('body').html());
    alert(iframeContents.filename);
    $("#newimgform")[0].reset();
});
$("#newupload").change(function() {
    $(this).attr("action", "uploadPicture.php")
                    .attr("method", "post")
                    .attr("MAX_FILE_SIZE", 5242880)
                    .attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data")
                    .attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data")
                    .attr("target", "postframe")
                    .submit();
});
```

You could alternatively unbind the `load` event handler each time it runs, but this seems unnecessary in your case. `$(this).unbind('load');` is all you would have to add to the `load` event handler.

Also you can optimize this, a lot. You are using the same selector over and over, when in jQuery we chain function calls.